# get json api data to display correct

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest, api

Question, why and how do i get my json api data to display. to display my api infomation

I am new to api and am trying

json data

```
[{"title":"One article - API 1 - 2017-04-25 15:43:20"},{"title":"Another article - API 1 - 2017-04-25 15:43:20"},{"title":"Great article - API 1 - 2017-04-25 15:43:20"}]
```

I have a small js file that im using to get my api

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#get-data').click(function () {
    var showData = $('#show-data');

    $.getJSON('https://some api ', function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      var items = data.title (function (item) {
        return title;
      });

      showData.empty();

      if (items.length) {
        var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
        var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
        showData.append(list);
      }
    });

    showData.text('Loading the JSON file.');
  });
});
```

I then have a html part to display the api info onlick

```
<body>
  <a href="#" id="get-data">Get JSON data</a>
    <div id="show-data"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>


   </body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no method `data.title()` you want [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control)

Scaled down version:

```
 $.getJSON('https://some api ', function(data) {
    // map title properties into flattened array
    var items = data.map(function(item) {
      return item.title;
    });

    if (items.length) {
      var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
      var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
      showData.append(list);
    }
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/aG3wXEZxFBNTd5IgXmGY?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: In this example i cant see where i call the external api

Comment: The only real change is `var items = data.map()` instead of `var items = data.title()` and how that gets returned as `item.title` ... all else would be the same

Comment: And what happens here if malicious html is returned in the title attribute of the data returned by the API? You now have XSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the items in data to build your HTML and then append it to the `showData` div.

I also changed how you are building your `<li>` a little bit for security purposes. If you set the HTML of the `<li>` equal to each item's title property coming back from `data`, and the title contains malicious HTML/scripts, your application has been successfully compromised with an XSS attack.

As a general rule of thumb, never set HTML unless you absolutely have to - especially if it is coming from a third-party source.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#get-data').click(function() {
    var showData = $('#show-data');
    $.getJSON('https://some api ', function(data) {
      showData.empty();
      var items = data.map(function(elem) {
        return $("<li />", {
          text: elem.title
        });
      });

      var list = $('<ul />').append(items);
      showData.append(list);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="get-data">Get JSON data</a>
<div id="show-data"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The **data** returned in $.getJSON is a collection of objects. That might have been clear to you while you consoled the response.

Now, loop through data and you can access each object and insert title into li.

See a sample code below:

```
data.map(function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.title) // use this in your <li>
})
```